# Install and run PlasticSCM client on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, plasticscm

I'm using Ubuntu (Linux 3.2.0-37-generic #58-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux). I've just installed PlasticSCM (only client) using the graphical installer (from PlasticSCM official download site).

The install process finished without problems, but the client doesn't get opened.

Then I tried to install using the Ubuntu/Debian packages (from https://www.plasticscm.com/plastic-for-linux/index.html), but there are some missing dependecies:

```
Err http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/5.0/Debian_6.0/ ./ plasticscm-libmono3-debugger-soft2.0-cil 3.0.3.1-1.1 404  Not Found
Err http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/5.0/Debian_6.0/ ./ plasticscm-libmono3-i18n-west2.0-cil 3.0.3.1-1.1 404  Not Found
Err http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/5.0/Debian_6.0/ ./ plasticscm-libmono3-system-runtime4.0-cil 3.0.3.1-1.1 404  Not Found
Err http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/5.0/Debian_6.0/ ./ plasticscm-libmono3-webmatrix-data4.0-cil 3.0.3.1-1.1 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/5.0/Debian_6.0/./all/plasticscm-libmono3-debugger-soft2.0-cil_3.0.3.1-1.1_all.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/5.0/Debian_6.0/./all/plasticscm-libmono3-i18n-west2.0-cil_3.0.3.1-1.1_all.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/5.0/Debian_6.0/./all/plasticscm-libmono3-system-runtime4.0-cil_3.0.3.1-1.1_all.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/5.0/Debian_6.0/./all/plasticscm-libmono3-webmatrix-data4.0-cil_3.0.3.1-1.1_all.deb  404  Not Found
```

I can see the exec "plasticscm" in the command line (installed in my first try with the GUI installed I guess) but it throws this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.KnownColors ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libgdiplus.so.0.0.0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal (IntPtr hdc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr display_handle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Color.get_Black () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeVisualStyles..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox+MessageBoxForm..ctor (IWin32Window owner, System.String text, System.String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, Boolean displayHelpButton) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox+MessageBoxForm..ctor (IWin32Window owner, System.String text, System.String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean displayHelpButton) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox/MessageBoxForm:.ctor (System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window,string,string,System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons,System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon,System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton,System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions,bool)
  at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show (IWin32Window owner, System.String text, System.String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Codice.I3.I3MessageBox.Show (IWin32Window window, System.String text, System.String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Codice.I3.I3MessageBox.Show (System.String text, System.String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ce.a (System.String A_0, System.String A_1, MessageBoxIcon A_2, IWin32Window A_3) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ce.a (System.String A_0, System.String A_1, MessageBoxIcon A_2, ISynchronizeInvoke A_3, IWin32Window A_4) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ce.a (System.String A_0, MessageBoxIcon A_1, ISynchronizeInvoke A_2, IWin32Window A_3) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ce.a (System.String A_0, System.Exception A_1, MessageBoxIcon A_2, ISynchronizeInvoke A_3, IWin32Window A_4) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ce.a (System.String A_0, System.Exception A_1, MessageBoxIcon A_2) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ce.b (System.Exception A_0) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at xk.a (System.String[] A_0) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

¿Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must have been some kind of problem with the repository server, I just installed the software from scratch and no error was shown.

Try updating your apt-get sources and reinstalling the plasticscm-server package. Something like

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall plasticscm-client plasticscm-server
```

should do the trick. However, I would recommend uninstalling your previous installation (which was performed using the downloaded installer package) by executing the script at `/opt/plasticscm5/uninstall.sh` first.

Comment: No 404 now. Great. Thanks.